# Algorithm to check whether we can pick k balls of different colours

Tags: algorithm

We have n boxes and balls of k different colors.Each container has few balls in it.We can select maximum one ball from each boxes.

Can we collect k balls of different colors?
Note: Each container has maximum one ball of a color.

**Example:**

Suppose we have 5 containers and 4 different colors A,B,C,D

```
Box1 - A, D
Box2 - C,B
Box3 - D, A
Box4 - D
Box5 - D
```

Here you can not choose 4  balls of color A,B,C,D from these boxes.The condition is that you can pick only one ball from each box.

Comment: Please give an example of a problem instance.

Comment: @Codor I have updated the question with an example.

Comment: While I wouldn't call this a variant on a sudoku problem, it's sufficiently similar that you should be able to use some of the same algorithms used for sudoku solvers that you could for this problem.  A simple example would be to use a backtracking algorithm.

Comment: Is this a variation of the Set Cover Problem? It certainly looks like a Covering problem.

Comment: @MSalters I suspect that you could prove this problem to be np-complete.  It certainly has that feel to it.

Comment: @MSalters No, this problem is squarely in P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a matching problem.

Start with a bipartite graph whose vertices are colors of balls and boxes, and whose edges are the relation "this ball is in that box".  You want to construct a maximum matching.  If that maximum matching includes every color of ball, then your answer is yes, otherwise no.

Use a standard algorithm for constructing a maximum matching in a bipartite graph.  The [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) will be simple to implement.  But the [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) will run faster.